# Maximize duplicity efficiency

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-s3, incremental-backup, duplicity

I'm creating incremental backups for a database. The size is around **8 GB** per dump.

I have a backup creation policy, that looks like this: *(don't worry, I already avoided collisions)*

- An increment every hour, every day. (saved in `/hourly`)
- An increment every day, at midnight. (saved in `/daily`)
- An increment every Sunday, at midnight. (saved in `/weekly`)
- An increment every 1st of the month, at midnight. (saved in `/monthly`)

All of these backups are saved in a **S3 bucket**.

The thing is, i need to maximize efficiency when creating and restoring to duplicity.

---

#### For example:

A dump takes approximately 30/40 minutes to restore. This is because my backup chain is almost a week old, and it has to download all the chain, decrypt and decompress each of the increment, one by one.

I tried doing the same with the backups that are done daily, and since less than a week happened, `duplicity` only had to download a few files, do the rest (decompress, decrypt), and *voilà*, it took 5 minutes, which is acceptable.

My idea is to create a new backup chain every week, but the last few days of the week, will have the most increments, thus, the slowest restore time.

I need some help to improve this time as much as it's possible, or at least, just improve it. While reading the **man page**, i came across some interesting flags, such as `--copy-blocksize`, `--full-if-older-than (to create a new chain every week)`, `--max-blocksize`, `--s3-multipart-chunk-size`, `--s3-multipart-max-procs`, `--s3-unencrypted-connection (maybe?)`.

What I'm asking is for advice to improve the time to restore a file with duplicity. Currently, I'm doing this, to restore the last backup available.

```bash
PASSPHRASE="<redacted>" duplicity restore s3://<redacted>/daily/ database-daily.sql
```

Also, an important fact is the hardware that I'm running this on:

```
  Server Type:  ccx43 (ID: 99)
  ID:       99
  Name:     ccx43
  Description:  CCX43 Dedicated CPU
  Cores:    16
  CPU Type: dedicated
  Memory:   64 GB
  Disk:     160 GB
  Storage Type: local
  OS flavor:    debian
  OS version:   12
```